# Jmeter Add Variable to CSV Variable

Tags: variables, csv, jmeter

I have a variable ${joinuserid} with integer Value which is generated by Regex Extractor.

If I put the variable directly to HTTP Request. It works.

Now, I have a CSV file with Variable :

```
connector,element2,elementID
```

and The CSV File contain :

```
member,unit,${joinusertid}
```

It doesn't work, HTTP request will get "${joinusertid}" not the value of ${joinusertid}. Can you help me or give me another advice for my scenario?

Thank you.

Regards,

Stefio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${__evalVar(query)}`

So, `${__evalVar(elementID)}` will return the integer value of `joinuserid`.